# Evaluating user functions (client side js)

Tags: javascript

What projects are available, that allows me to evaluate user-provided javascript "safely" ?

Specifically, I want to allow users to `.map` a row of values, to produce a value. So typical input would be something like `parseInt(row[0].substring(0,4)) + row[3]`, which I want to evaluate client-side. The page with the user-evaluated javascript can be seen by other users, so I'd rather want something that doesn't open up alerts, and redirects users to other sites etc.

Comment: I have always used google caja but I think they shut it down. You can still find it and it allows you to add custom sanitizers quite easily so as not to strip out everything. https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/wiki/JsHtmlSanitizer

Comment: Yeah, caja seems to be what most people use, but as you said, it seems to be unsupported by now. I'm sure it's good enough for my purpose, but I was curious to see if there was any active projects.